# How to run a formula on multiple sets of filtered data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, filtering

I have around 12 columns of data and a complex formula that computes some value from that data. The formula involves `XIRR`, `MAP`, `GOOGLEFINANCE`, `INDEX`, `IF`, and other functions that refer to several columns, multiple times.

I have 2 columns on which I want to filter the data and run the same formula on that filtered data. That means there would be dozens of combinations based on the values in the 2 columns.

What is the easiest way to run the formula on all such possible filtered data?

Here are the options that I explored

1. Everywhere in the formula where I am referencing some column, I replace it with a FILTER function. And then copy paste this formula on multiple cells, each with a different value of filter condition. There are a total of 4 columns I need to refer and I need to refer each of them 4 times in 4 independent nested formulas. This will make already long formula(7 lines currently) too big to manage.
2. Create a new sheet and populate the data in that sheet from master sheet using FILTER with the desired conditions and then copy paste the original formula from Master sheet to this new sheet so that the formula now runs only on the filtered data. While this is neat, I cannot collate the result of multiple filtered data in a single sheet. Either I'll have to create a new sheet for every possible filtered data or I can check the result of only 1 at any given point of time

Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Perhaps a way where I can use option 2 but not have to create multiple sheets? Some way where I do not need to store the result of my FILTER function and run my complex formula on top of the output of the FILTER?

Something like

```
=(FILTER(A2:H, A2:A = 'X1', B2:B = 'Y1'))MY_COMPLEX_FORMULA <---- In cell 1
=(FILTER(A2:H, A2:A = 'X2', B2:B = 'Y2'))MY_COMPLEX_FORMULA <---- In cell 2 and so on
```

So that MY_COMPLEX_FORMULA can work on the output of the FILTER and refer to those cells and columns naturally without storing the result of FILTER anywhere on the sheet

Comment: Please share [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), such as a sample/copy of your spreadsheet and expected result. This will help us understand your concern better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question would be much easier if you included a sample set, however, assuming your *complex formula* is always producing a single result (instead of an array), then it is likely you could use LET to create a temporary array for each row of a calculation and then pass that as a parameter to your complex formula.

Something like this:

```
=let(fullRng,A$2:H,cleanRng,filter(fullRng,if(CHOOSECOLS(fullRng,1)=X2,
choosecols(fullRng,2)=Y2)),ComplexFormula(cleanRange)
```

This creates a filtered range in each ROW, but doesn't actually display it. Your complex formula would have to be doing something to minimize this so that it doesn't take up more than a cell as it would spill into itself.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I google a lot but couldn't arrive at any search result that could point me to this LET function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 1 Follow up question. If, after filtering, `cleanRange` is a grid with many rows and columns, how can I refer to any particular column inside the final formula expression? Currently I just filtered each column separately so that I can easily refer them

Comment: I upvoted your answer immediately. I just haven't posted too many question on SO to know that an upvote is different from "accepting an answer".

Comment: Thanks. I'm impressed you upvoted the answer with only a 23 rating... Regardless, I don't quite understand your followup question, but you might consider looking at using the function choosecols to specify a column? So if you wanted to filter column 3 you could `=filter(cleanRange,chooseCols(cleanRange,3)="Something")` Hope that helps, or else go ahead post a new question. Thanks.